# Interop: C++ COM client with C# COM server byte array parameter - is array copied in/out or accessed directly?

Tags: c#, interop, c++-cli, com-interop

We have a C#/.Net COM server (COM-visible assembly) with the following interface & class declarations:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid( "..." )]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface ITest
{
    void TestMethod( [In] int nNumElements, 
                     [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=0)] byte [] bArray );
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid( "..." )]
[ClassInterface( ClassInterfaceType.None )]
[ProgId( "CSCOMServer.CSTest" )]
public class CSTest : ITest
{
    public void TestMethod( int nNumElements, byte [] bArray )
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < bArray.Length; i++)
        {
            bArray [i] = (byte)i;
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting IDL/typelib is:

```
...
interface ITest : IUnknown {
    HRESULT _stdcall TestMethod(
                    [in] long nNumElements, 
                    [in, out] unsigned char* bArray);
};

...
coclass CSTest {
    interface _Object;
    [default] interface ITest;
};
```

The goal is to be able to utilize this from a C++ COM client, which works fine using the following:

```
int iSize = 10;
ITest *test;
byte *buf  = (byte*)CoTaskMemAlloc( iSize * sizeof(byte) );
CoCreateInstance( CLSID_CSTest, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ITest, (void **) &test );
test->TestMethod( iSize, buf );
```

The buffer is allocated by C++ and passed to C# for population.
All works well and upon the completion of TestMethod() the C++ array (buf) contains correct values set by the C# method.

The question is about efficiency:
Does the Interop wrapper perform array copying during marshaling ("In" phase) and then back ("Out" phase) OR does the C# method operate directly on the passed in memory (which may be pinned)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a copy is definitely required here since you ask for a structural change.  The CLR *must* create a managed array object to meet the byte[] argument type requirement.  And the source array isn't in any way usable as-is since it is nothing but a raw chunk of memory.  The other way around (byte[] to unsigned char*) can work but that's not the case here.

The normal COM automation type for arrays is SAFEARRAY btw, no speed advantage but there are a lot more COM clients that could use your server.

Comment: I agree that SAFEARRAY is the way to go. In our case we're stuck dealing with a legacy COM IDL/DLL written in C++ that the managed version (C#) needs to mimic. Hence the conformant array method parameter... Of course having *possibly* double copying of rather large arrays is not very appealing. Unfortunately the documentation is not very crystal clear about copying or lack thereof during marshaling in this particular case... If you have any links to the documentation (MSDN or otherwise) on this topic, it would certainly help as well. Thanks a lot for your input!

Comment: I have to agree with this answer - given the method signature I specified, a copy would have to be made. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In this case a reference will be passed between unmanaged and the managed code.
The "pinning optimization" do that for you in certain cases even if the in/out parameter is not specified (but for use as a tlib one always have to specify the in/out modifier).

You can assume that single dimension arrays of primitive types always will be pinned (passed by reference) between unmanaged and managed code running on the same apartment.

You can read more about it here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6(v=vs.80).aspx

More about "pinning optimization":
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23acw07k.aspx

Comment: What I am still unclear though, is that we're dealing with a managed COM server and unmanaged client, whereas the articles mentioned deal with the reverse situation. Also, the very last sentence of the [Passing Array Parameters to .NET Code / C-style arrays] section mentions that *The interop marshaler uses the CoTaskMemAlloc and CoTaskMemFree methods to allocate and retrieve memory...*  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6(v=vs.100).aspx#cpcondefaultmarshalingforarraysanchor3)  Does that imply that the marshaler *may* allocate memory for copying?

Comment: I think so alex. Sometimes the marshaler could do a copy of an array depending on apartment model and array type. But, on array of primitive types I think this is not the case. Primitive types stored in memory are read "as is" by managed and unmanaged code. An Int32 for example is represented in memory in the same way on both managed and unmanaged code. Although MS documentation isn't clear about this, there is no purpose on do Int32 marshaling to the same representation that it already is  ;)

Comment: But in other data structures the marshaler must do some work on that array, so it must simulate an in/out for both sides but still make a copy of the array.

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot! It would certainly be nice to determine dynamically whether a copy took place or not...